# Carriage return location after scanning data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

When I scan data into cell B1, I want it to go to A2.  I have my advanced setting (after pressing Enter, move selection to Direction "Right"), which works for moving from Cell A1 to B1.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Holding `Shift` while pressing enter (or tab) will cause the selection to move in the direction opposite the bound direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an **event handler** to the workbook.

Alt+f11, double-click "ThisWorkbook" from the project tree, and put code such as this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim cellrange As String

    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        cellrange = "A" & Trim(Str(Target.Row + 1))
        Application.Goto Reference:=ActiveSheet.Range(cellrange), Scroll:=true
    End If
End Sub
```

This will be run every time you change a value in the workbook. If the column you just altered is B (column 2), then the subroutine will jump to column A of the whatever the next row is.